# undefined this after using bind on module function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm experiencing a strange issue with bind

I've read :
[Bind MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

And countless SO questions where everyone seems to forget that bind **returns a bound function**

This is not the case here.

### Example

I export the following object

```
const ErrorStore = {
  clearError : () => {
    this.setState({
      // removed for demo purpose
    });
  }
};

export default ErrorStore;
```

I then import this object like this:

```
import error from 'ErrorStore';
class AppStoreProvider extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {

    console.log(this); // AppStoreProvider
    const test = error.clearError.bind(this); 
    test(); // error , cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    
  }
}
```

### The Problem

This code throws an error when `test` is invoked, it seems that `bind` is not binding `AppStoreProvider` to the `clearError` function.

### More Detail

This example i am showing is a very dumbed down version of the actual implementation. **However, it still throws an error**

The implementation uses the following function to create a **new object** from the imported store object, but with its functions bound to `AppStoreProvider`:

```
bindStore(store) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(store)
      .map(key => (typeof store[key] === 'function' ?
        { [key] : store[key].bind(this) } :
        { [key] : store[key] })));
  }
```

### Question

Does `bind` work across files like this?
Why is `this` undefined

### Edit 06/11/2018

After posting this question I realised the function is correctly bound when defined as a named function.

```
export function clearError(){

  this.setState({
    error   : undefined,
    isError : false
  });

}
```

Comment: As soon as I posted this, I figured out what the problem was. It has to do with the anonymous functions declared in `ErrorStore`. I will post an answer tomorrow explaining my error in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind arrow functions as their context is always determined lexically (the context they were declared in, that cannot be changed). Instead use a regular function that dynamically determines its context:

```
 const ErrorStore = {
  clearError() { // <<<
     this.setState({
       // removed for demo purpose
     });
   }
};
```

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer, I realised this as soon as I posted. I just instinctively wrote arrow functions out of habit without even thinking.